# Internal server error works fine in server and iOS

Tags: android, json, node.js, http-post

I am trying to call backend node js server. 
I get Internal error as response though it works fine in iOS and server. Server sends back a response code as 500 and with error message data. How can I parse the error response code and parse the json error message. All the error messages goes to exception
Code:

```
httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpPostRequest);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please check your internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String strResponse = null;
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.e("BackEndServer ", "Response: " + strResponse);
```

Logs:

```
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at com.amazonaws.androidtest.MessageReceivingService.sendRegistrationIdToBackend(MessageReceivingService.java:165)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at com.amazonaws.androidtest.MessageReceivingService.access$1(MessageReceivingService.java:123)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at com.amazonaws.androidtest.MessageReceivingService$1.doInBackground(MessageReceivingService.java:111)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-20 12:21:44.870: W/System.err(29129):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-20 12:21:44.880: W/System.err(29129):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
02-20 12:21:44.880: W/System.err(29129):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
02-20 12:21:44.880: W/System.err(29129):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
02-20 12:21:44.880: E/BackEndServer(29129): Response: null
```

Comment: If you want to handle parsing the JSON response you probably shouldn't be using the `BasicResponseHandler` but use something more specific. If you are just looking to debug the problem, assuming the node server is yours I'd just look there to see the exception causing the 500.

Comment: Thank you I parsed the JSON response and it worked